# CF How to list all the files in the root directory of my project

Tags: cloud-foundry

So, by now I have managed to put one of my applications on CF but I can't access the infrastructure due to the corporate model of my organization and hence its not possible for me to check the pushed code-base by accessing the server itself,

Hence, I was wondering whether there is an option to display the project tree/structure as it is present on the server instance ?

I have tried the following command but the same doesn't seem to work,

[files - Print out a list of files in a directory or the contents of a specific file of an app running on the DEA backend
Directory](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/files.html)

**Output to the command present in the CF Documentation**

[image]

> Also, I see that it has been written that this works for a DEA backend
>   , what does DEA stands for ?
>
> I am running a nodejs app should this command work for me ?

**Why I need the directory structure ?**

> I have setup a node app which serves the html and css pages via
>   webpack build tool. So basically the html pages have the injected css
>   & js file path at runtime. On my local machine I do have the access to
>   this generated folder and I also find that the referenced css and js
>   executes but the same is not working on my deployed app hence I want
>   to understand what exactly is the folder structure there for the
>   deployed app.

**UPDATE**

> One strange thing , today I also tried to deploy the same
>   project on my own pivotal cloud services instance using CF and to my
>   surprise it just worked like charm as it were working locally on my
>   machine i.e. no path issues which I wanted to rectify by having a look
>   at the folder structure. Maybe it is something related to my server
>   configuration as we are not using PWS with CF and AWS at the Iaas
>   layer.
>
> We here have a concept of Endpoints registration in the developed tool
>   where the hosted apps/components are configured . Possibly that is
>   causing this issue, once resolved I will share the reason and fix.

**SOLUTION**

> So, it didn't work for me because I was behind a proxy and hence I
>   eventually ended up creating an SSH connection string and an OTP.
>   Then, I used **PUTTY** with the same proxy settings and ssh
>   **url:port** to access the directory structure.

Comment: Why do you need to know how the directory structure is on the container? What exactly is your use case? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @K.AJ , I have added the use case .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PCF platform Ops team has enabled the `cf ssh` access then you can run `cf ssh <app-name>` to ssh into the app container. You can then see how the files are laid out.

DEA stands for Droplet Execution Agent. DEA is the container orchestration engine in OSS CF. On PCF, DEA has been replaced with DIEGO container orchestration engine.

Comment: Oh , I get it now. For most of the things the Ops team has the control. :)  thanks for the additional info on DEA and DIEGO. 

One more thing , for the css and js resource which gives a 404 I get an error stating that there is no endpoint registered ? Is there any requirement for endpoint registration for all the locations/paths ?

Comment: Your file structure should basically be the same as in your local machine. The `cf push` command is going to upload everything from the current directory, in the same structure, or it's going to upload everything from the directory set with `cf push -p`. Everything pushed ends up under `/home/vcap/app` (`/app` is a symlink to this directory, so that works too). In general, you'd want to use relative paths to resources though and you don't have to worry about this. If you need to generate full paths, try to use `$HOME`, which references `/home/vcap/app` or `$PWD` which reference the same.

Comment: If you need to poke around, `cf ssh` is the best/easiest option. If that's disabled by your platform operator you don't have lot of choice. What I like to do is `cf push -c 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080'`. This runs a simple web server from the root of your app's files, instead of your app. You can then navigate to your app and browse around (it shows indexes). Just be careful as anyone with the URL can see that. You can turn this off by running `cf push -c null`. That falls back to using the buildpack's detected start command.

Comment: So, if I get an error like endpoint not registered for the js / css / image files i.e. MSG exception: There is no registered endpoint: https://my.web.page.address/images/c1.png is there anything that I need to make sure or register ?

Comment: @DanielMikusa , To simulate the same scenario I did try with my project on the public cloud of Pivotal and surprisingly it worked as expected. What could then be the problem at my server ? To me , it looks like the configuration of both is same as well.

Comment: Not sure, but watch `cf logs <app>`. You'll see entries with `[RTR]` for each request that hits your app. If you don't see these, then the requests are not making it to your app. That'll let you figure out if the problem is upstream or in your app. It's is likely upstream as your app works fine on a different Cloud Foundry environment & that should be very similar to your CF environment.